# Updating a variable in a linked variable group with $(Build.BuildId) from a Linux pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to update a variable in a linked variable group with $(Build.BuildId) from a Linux pipeline.  I see a few examples using the @echo ##vso[task.setvariable command, but can't get it to work because I don't think I'm referencing the source or destination right.

The linked variable group is NightlyBuildID and the variable is LinuxBuildID.

Here's one of my many attempts:
@echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=LinuxBuildID]$(Build.BuildId)

Answer (score 1):

The `$(variable)` syntax is only valid within the build editor interface. Within a script, you have to reference it as an environment variable. Periods are replaced with underscores.

Thus, in Linux, `$(Build.BuildId)` would be accessed as `$BUILD_BUILDID`.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  Using that syntax, I can see the correct values of these variables in the log after execution, but I still can't modify the variable WINDOWSBUILDID in the variable group.  I first manually set WINDOWSBUILDID to 99 in the Team Services UI, then run this script:
echo $WINDOWSBUILDID
echo $BUILD_BUILDID
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$WINDOWSBUILDID]$BUILD_BUILDID"
echo $WINDOWSBUILDID
The output is:
99
6100
99

Comment: The correct syntax is `##vso[task.setvariable variable=WINDOWSBUILDID;]$BUILD_BUILDID`. Note the lack of a dollar sign in front of the variable name. Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this can't be done, according to the link below.  I'll have to come up with a work around, bummer.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32083207-allow-variables-in-variable-groups-to-be-settable